# Extraction of data from HDF at different pressure level

Tags: r, hdfs, extract, hdf5, netcdf

I am trying to extract a variable named `Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn` at a point location (`lon=40`, `lat=34`) at different pressure level (`825.40198`, `681.29102`, `464.16000`, `316.22699` hPa) from multiple hdf files

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)
# read file 
nc <- nc_open("E:/Ozone/test1.nc")
list_col1 <- as.list(list.files("E:/Ozone/", pattern = "*.hdf",
                                full.names = TRUE))
> attributes(nc$var) #using a single hdf file to check its variables
$names
 [1] "Data Fields/Latitude"                "Data Fields/Longitude"              
 [3] "Data Fields/O3"                      "Data Fields/O3DataCount"            
 [5] "Data Fields/O3Maximum"               "Data Fields/O3Minimum"              
 [7] "Data Fields/O3StdDeviation"          "Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn"        
 [9] "Data Fields/Pressure"                "Data Fields/TotColDensDataCount"    
[11] "Data Fields/TotColDensMaximum"       "Data Fields/TotColDensMinimum"      
[13] "Data Fields/TotColDensStdDeviation"  "Data Fields/TotalColumnDensity"     
[15] "HDFEOS INFORMATION/StructMetadata.0" "HDFEOS INFORMATION/coremetadata" 

> pres <- ncvar_get(nc, "Data Fields/Pressure") #looking at pressure level from single file of hdf
> pres
 [1] 825.40198 681.29102 464.16000 316.22699 215.44400 146.77901 100.00000  68.12950  46.41580  31.62290
[11]  21.54430  14.67800  10.00000   6.81291   4.64160

ncin <- raster::stack(list_col1,
                       varname = "Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn",
                       ncdf=TRUE)
#cannot extract using the following code
o3 <- ncvar_get(list_col1,attributes(list_col1$var)$names[9]) 
"Error in ncvar_get(list_col1, attributes(list_col1$var)$names[9]) : 
  first argument (nc) is not of class ncdf4!"
#tried to extract pressure levels
> prsr <- raster::stack(list_col1,varname = "Data Fields/Pressure",ncdf=TRUE)
"Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'stack': varname: Data Fields/Pressure does not exist in the file. Select one from:
Data Fields/O3, Data Fields/O3DataCount, Data Fields/O3Maximum, Data Fields/O3Minimum, Data Fields/O3StdDeviation, Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn, Data Fields/TotColDensDataCount, Data Fields/TotColDensMaximum, Data Fields/TotColDensMinimum, Data Fields/TotColDensStdDeviation, Data Fields/TotalColumnDensity"

#tried using index
#Point location can also be written as below 1 deg by 1 deg resolution
lonIdx <- which(lon >32 & lon <36)  
latIdx <- which(lat >38 & lat <42)  
presIdx <- which(pres >= 400 & pres <= 900)


#also tried
# Option 2 -- subset using array indexing
o3 <- ncvar_get(list_col1,'Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn')
"Error in ncvar_get(list_col1, "Data Fields/OzoneTropColumn") : 
  first argument (nc) is not of class ncdf4!"
extract2 <- o3[lonIdx, latIdx, presIdx, ]
```

How to I extract these values vertically at each pressure level ? (`SM=Some value`)

I would like the output in following way at location (`lon=40`, `lat=34`):

```
Pressure             1           2         3          4          5 ....       10
825.40198          SM1           SM2      SM3        SM4         SM5...       SM10
681.29102          SM11          SM12     
464.16000 
316.22699          SM..          SM..      SM..       SM..        SM..        SM..
```

Appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Please do not vandalize any posts on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with how netcdf4 and raster name each of the layers in the file. And perhaps some confusion with trying to create a multilayer object from multiple ncdf at once.

I would do the following, using only raster: Load a single netCDF, using `stack()` or `brick()`. This will load the file as a multilayer object in R. Use `names()` to identify what is the name of the Ozone layer *according to the raster package*.

```
firstraster <- stack("E:/Ozone/test1.nc")
names(firstraster)
```

Once you find out the name, you can just execute a reading of all objects as `stack()`, extract the information on points of interest, without even assembling all layers in a single stack.

```
Ozonelayername <- "put name here"
files <- list.files("E:/Ozone/", pattern = "*.hdf", full.names = TRUE)
stacklist <- lapply(files, stack)
Ozonelayerlist <- lapply(stacklist, "[[", "Ozonelayername")
```

The line above will output a list of rasters objects (not stacks or bricks, just plain rasters), with only the layer you want.

Now we just need to execute an extract on each of these layers. `sapply()` will format that neatly in a matrix for us.

```
pointsofinterest <-  expand.grid(32:36,38:42)
values <- sapply(Ozonelayerlist, extract, pointsofinterest)
```

I can test it, since I do not have the data, but I assume this would work.